# Java Runtime.exec() with ssh on Linux Issues

Tags: java, linux, ssh, runtime.exec

I am trying to start a new process using Runtime.exec(), but my problem lies within using ssh to remote in and then run a java program there. Code:

```
test = "ssh -t username@host java packageName.ClassName portNumber (Other command line args for this class)"
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", test});
```

this doesn't fail or catch, but I need to be able to see the stdout for the newly running process and I don't.

Note: if I run `ssh -t username@host java packageName.ClassName portNumber (Other command line args for this class)` from the command line it works fine. I have the host setup to not require a password by using ssh keys.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Process.getInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) to obtain the output from the sub-process being created.

See [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) for a good discussion on `Runtime.exec`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can ask for an input stream that corresponds to the stdout of the process and then print it on your standard output. If you need to see it after it executes, just call `waitFor()` method on the process so it finishes before you start printing.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) to access returned process's stdout. You can also use facilities provided by [`ProcessBuilder.Redirect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html).